# Windows Form TreeView - PNG Image Background

Tags: winforms, treeview, icons

We are using famfamfam png icons.  When TreeNodes are assigned one of these images there is an odd blue background colored inside the icons.  How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be something to do with the bit depth of the PNGs?

Try exporting them at a different depth, such as 32bit, and make sure your associated ImageList is set to a sensible depth (should match the images ! - I'd suggest everything is 32bit).

Failing that, you could always use the Owner Draw functionality, or create a new component that inherits from TreeView.